# strut and strutbox

Tags: strut

The definition of a `\strut` in LaTeX is given in the source as:

```
211 \newbox\strutbox
212 \def\strut{\relax\ifmmode\copy\strutbox\else\unhcopy\strutbox\fi}
```

Shoudn't a `\strutbox`, give an empty box? AS you can see from the example below, it prints the ligature `ae`, if I include `fixltx2e`
and the ligature `ff` if I don't. `\strut` works as expected.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\begin{document}
    \strutbox
    \texttt{\strutbox} 
    \textit{\strutbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `\copy\strutbox` to get the box. The definition `\newbox\strutbox` merely allocates a box number for the strutbox, then assigns that number to `\strutbox` using `\chardef`. Hence `\strutbox` in isolation typesets the character in the current font with the same number as the box number allocated to strutbox.